# 90s teen "counter-Earth" TV show; kid goes to a parallel Earth on the other side of the sun

Tags: story-identification, tv

I remember a TV show from the 90s in which a boy from our Earth somehow ends up on a parallel Earth in a pre-industrial society. IIRC, it's a counter-Earth on the other side of the sun.

The part I remember most distinctly is that he meets a girl of a similar age, and he tried to explain a heliocentric solar system to her by rotating around her. The villagers mistake this as some kind of courtship dance and get upset.

I have a vague recollection of it being maybe a BBC or CBC production, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the details aren't completely right, that sounds like [*Spellbinder*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0112174/) (1995).

An accident involving high voltage sends the male teenage protagonist to an alternate world that is pre-industrial, but relics of older and more advanced civilization still existed, like special suits of armor that fired bolts of electricity.  He does meet a local girl, but I can't remember the details well enough to say if there was a courtship misunderstanding or not.

I think an eclipse occurred in an early episode and the locals had a primitive explanation for it.  Based on that, it seems likely he tried to explain the solar system at some point.

It was an Australian/Polish production.

Comment: I've located the episode with the eclipse and I've taken the liberty of editing it into your answer.

Comment: Wow, yeah, that's the one. It's amazing how hard it is to get details right, but the specific mise-en-scene is right there. Thanks!