# 90's TV series where a boy goes to another dimension through portal near power lines

Tags: story-identification, tv, parallel-universe, medieval

I am desperately trying to remember a name of a TV series probably from 90's. I remember these points:

- A boy goes to another dimension through a portal near a power lines.
- This dimension has a sort of medieval world.
- There are bad guys with an electric suit and they throw lightning balls at the good guys. Before throwing, they always "charge" the suit by touching with forearms which has electrodes.
- In one episode, the main character creates a gun powder.

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/181212/tv-show-about-teens-with-magic-armor-fighting-a-villainess/181232#181232 and https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146382/90s-teen-counter-earth-tv-show-kid-goes-to-a-parallel-earth-on-the-other-side

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm pretty certain that this is an Australian TV show from the 1990s called [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)).

- It has power suits which can throw balls of lightening, and are recharged by rubbing the cuffs together.
- In the first episode, the main characters attempt to create gunpowder, and in a later episode a main character is forced to create gun powder by their captors.
- Crossing between dimensions involves electricity.
- The other dimension involves a medieval style magical world orientated around magnetism and electricity.

Comment: Yes! This is it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The entire show is available on youtube.

Comment: Australian/Polish

Answer (score 12):

That would be [Spellbinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spellbinder_(TV_series)).

> A group of teenagers go on a school camp in the Blue Mountains in
>   Australia. While at the camp, **Paul Reynolds accidentally goes into a
>   parallel universe**. This other world is inhabited by a more hierarchic
>   and technologically different society, ruled by a group of people
>   known as Spellbinders. Paul meets a girl there named Riana, and they
>   become friends.
>
> The Spellbinders have discovered the power to create and manipulate
>   static electricity. They fly in gigantic copper-coloured machines that
>   utilise large rotating orange crystals, presumably creating some form
>   of magnetic levitation. The Spellbinders often use their power for
>   good, but some abuse this power and use their discoveries for
>   malevolence. One such malevolent Spellbinder is Ashka, who often
>   manages to hide her true nature. Common people are often "banished"
>   for their misdeeds, and sometimes Spellbinders are banished, also, if
>   they are proven to have done wrong.
>
> There is tension from Paul's forays into the land of the Spellbinders
>   and his attempts to return to his own universe, and also from
>   conversations Paul has with his friends across the barrier between the
>   two universes. Paul and Riana's escapes also add tension, as do the
>   interactions between Spellbinders.
>
> Paul is eventually able to travel back home, but he is forced to take
>   Riana with him in order to save her. Later, when Paul is able to take
>   Riana back home, the Spellbinder Ashka follows Paul as he later
>   returns home. Ashka seeks the unwitting help of Paul's father in
>   making her a new high-tech 'flying suit' to replace her power suit in
>   order to make her more powerful than the other Spellbinders.
>
> However, Paul manages to expose her scheme and defeat Ashka, who is
>   returned as an outcast to the Spellbinder world, while Riana becomes
>   the new apprentice to Correon. In order to keep the Spellbinder world
>   safe from the more advanced people from "modern" world, the gateway
>   between the two universes is closed permanently.